# How to run jquery before pageload

Tags: jquery

in my jsp page i have two divs and a textbox with a default value as follows

```
<input type="text" value="somevalue"  id="box"/>
<div id="first" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="second"></div>
```

In script tag i have written as follows

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($("#box").val()=='somevalue')
    {
        $('first').show();
        $('second').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

The above code is running fine..but when the page loads the second div is coming for 1 second and then switching to first div..and i dont want that switching to appear..

Comment: `$('first').show();
$('second').hide();`  are you sure that you are not getting any error ?, you are missing '#' in the id selector

Comment: Start with the second div also as hidden. Run your jquery and decide what you want to show.

Comment: sorry i missed it here.but i have written it correctly in my code.

Comment: In which section have you placed the `<script>` tag?

Comment: @ryadavilli hey when i hide the second div am able to see blank page first for one sec and then the div is loading.

Comment: So what is it that you want to be shown by default?

Comment: @Aditi in <head></head> section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it's in a `JSP` page, so you can put conditional logic in on the server-side and determine which of the two `<div>` elements should be hidden before it even gets to the browser. There's absolutely no reason to use jQuery to solve this, and doing so is (in my opinion) the wrong approach.

Assuming you're using the [JSTL core](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) tag library:

```
<c:set var="yourValue" value="somevalue"/>
<input type="text" value="somevalue"  id="box"/>
<div id="first" <c:if test="${yourValue != 'somevalue'}">style="display:none"</c:if>></div>

<div id="second" <c:if test="${yourValue == 'somevalue'}">style="display:none"</c:if>></div>
```

Comment: thanks anthony your approach looks good. I searched for this type of solution but am unable to write the condition, that checks with the textbox value..

Comment: can u please tell me how to access the textbox value in if condition which was written in div.

Comment: @user1797637 Where does the textbox value come from? In a JSP page I'd expect it to be coming from some kind of Java bean associated with the page.

Comment: if it is bean variable am able to retrieve and it is not a bean variable

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this, you are missing id selector. '#' in the selector

```
$('#first').show();
$('#second').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML change all divs to hidden.

```
<input type="text" value="somevalue"  id="box"/>
<div id="first" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="second" style="display:none"></div>
```

And then in your JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
      // show only the boxes based on your conditions. This is just an example.
    if($("#box").val()=='somevalue')
    {
        $('#first').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#second').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ravi copy paste error. Corrected it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can set style="display:none" to both the div, and then show the div accroding to the value.

```
<input type="text" value="somevalue"  id="box"/>
<div id="first" style="display:none"></div> 
<div id="second" style="display:none"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($("#box").val()=='somevalue') { $('#first').show(); }
    else  { $('#second').show(); }
});
</script>
```

Comment: if this is the case then what is the need for this line `$('#second').hide();`

Comment: @sachin hey when i hide the second div am able to see blank page first for one sec and then the div is loading

Comment: $(document).ready --  Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: @sachinkulkarni so tell me how to execute that jquery before div loaded.since the page is first loaded and the query is executing second the deviation is appearing.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to execute jquery before page (DOM) is loaded. its client side script and how it can read value of element (in your case input )  if it is not in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#first,#second").css("display", "none");
($("#box").val() == 'somevalue' ? $('#first').show(); : $('#second').show();)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide some explanation of how it works.